# Publish SQL tables to CKAN

Tags: database, publish, ckan

I am new in publishing data to CKAN and I want to ask if it is possible to publish some tables from an external database to CKAN.

I managed to have a CKAN instance with the datastore extension up and running but I haven't figured out yet if I need to have the data saved in the datastore or if I can connect my external DB to CKAN directly.

If I must use the datastore extension how can I connect it with my data?